# remote pinimage on an iphone mapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, annotations, mapkit

i want to display remote images as pins on my map view i tried this way but this dont work

```
annotationView.image = resizedImage;
annotationView.opaque = NO;
UIImageView *sfIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"here the image URL"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

imageNamed takes a file from your local application bundle.

You want:

```
UIImageView *sfIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"here is the image URL"]]];
```

I don't recommend doing it this way though because it'll block the main UI thread. You should consider loading the image data for your pin asynchronously first.